# issue with regular expressions in excel?

Tags: excel

Here Is the formula which I am currently using :

```
=IF(AND('Row Data'!$J2="p",'Row Data'!$K2>0,OR(ISNA('Row Data'!$X2),'Row Data'!$X2=0),'Row Data'!$V2>0,'Row Data'!$V2<>"0000-00-00"),'Row Data'!A2,"")
```

The first part of the "OR" works perfectly fine but the second part won't work which is this part `"'Row Data'!$X2=0"`
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there is no expression being evaluated in OR(ISNA('Row Data'!$X2,  the second part has $X2=0 what is the first part evaluating?

Comment: in the x column i want to select the ones that has these values: '0,#N/A'. the first part select the ones that has "#N/A" values

Comment: the syntax is =OR(logical1,logical2...) however I suggest you break each expression into a separate True,False evaluation in a separate cell to see what is happening.

Comment: every thing works fine, the problem is that I can't fix it in a way that or section work completely. the result that it threw me only select the ones in the x column that has the "0" value.